# Whats the deal with the named html entity for $ (&dollar;)

Tags: html, ascii, html-entities

I have a fairly simple question. There is a named HTML entity in *most* references for the dollar sign, and it is what you would expect it to be; `&dollar;`.

But in other references, this is missing, and tell you only the numeric entity is available (`&#36;`).

As I remember, the named entity didn't exist for a long time because the `$` is part of the standard ASCII set. And due to this earlier/older versions of IE and other browsers don't support this entity.

So what's the deal with this currently? I am looking for what the support for the named entity is and why this wasn't supported in the first place...

Here's a [reference](http://www.entitycode.com/#currency-content) to all the currency symbols where strangely enough only the dollar doesn't have a named entity.

Here is a [small example](http://codepad.org/xCxWZWsu) of what I am talking about when you use a dollar + int. And yes, I know that in this simple example I could have just escaped the dollar sign with a slash but believe me when I say that making it an entity when I save the string is the sanest solution in my case.

Regardless of my example, I am still curious what the support for the `&dollar;` entity is.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What should it matter if a character reference `&dollar;` exists or not?

Comment: @RoToRa it's a little more semantic, I needed to use an entity because I was doing regex replaces on strings with these in it, and since $1 references to possible match found in the regex it would convert any $\d to 0. But the support for numeric entities in clients is usually lower than named entities I found this very curious.

Comment: I don't see why one would need to use an entity because of regular expressions. Could you give some concrete code showing your problem?

Comment: Updated my question with an example even though that will not help you answer my question.

Comment: Ah, ok. The thing is that a dollar happens to be a special character in replacement strings, and the only proper (and sane) thing to do *is* to escape them with black slashes. If you don't need the back reference feature here, you could simply use a function to do the escaping such as: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#103985 . Escaping them with HTML character references is a sign of sloppy work IMHO, because you'll get problems if you need to use the same string outside a HTML document, for example a text-only email or generating a PDF.

Comment: As I mentioned before, I am well aware it isn't a great solution, I know very well how to escape these strings for regexes. Just that this case is for a really old project which shouldn't have time invested in it anymore, it is simply not worth it, but it will have to run until its replacement is ready. I was asking about the html entity specifically and not the edge case why I needed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official list of entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) doesn't list it, so I'd file it under “some browsers may have had support for it, don't rely on it, though.”

Generally, entities were needed to represent non-ASCII characters when the document character set was limited by ASCII. Nowadays with UTF-8 the most frequent character set on the web I think we can finally move past named entities and just use the characters directly.

Answer (score 0):

The only sane solution is to use preg_quote() when using input for regular expressions. Otherwise you need to use html-enities for . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : - too.

Comment: I know how to escape strings for use in regular expressions. It was not my question.